# ArcPy failed to draw?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, raster

My ArcMap 10.6 Python code for creating a specific raster isn't working. The code is fine but the output keeps saying failed to draw.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\npenme2\Desktop\Faunalyze\Right_Femur.gdb'
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
(u'Feature_hul',u'Feature_KB3_Left_Humerus_14502_RC1',u'Feature_KB4_Left_Humerus_14515_RC1',u'KB1_Left_Humerus_14476_RC',u'KB2_Left_Humerus_14489_RC',u'KB5_Left_Humerus_14528_RC',u'KB5_Left_Humerus_14528_RC_zeronew1')
r1 = sum(Raster(r) for r in rasters)
r2 = sum(Con(r, 1, 0, 'Value > 0') for r in rasters)
avg_rast = FloatDivide(r1, r2)
avg_rast.save('Total_Left_HUmerus')
```

Also it's taking an extremely long time to process.

Comment: do the inputs display properly on top of each others ?

Comment: The code is not fine, because sum(rasters) is nonsense.

Comment: The sum isn't nonsense. It executes the same function as the raster addition map algebra under spatial analysis tools